# Near IF Syntax Error (SQLite3+Objective-C) (UPDATE IF NOT EXISTS)

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I am experiencing the error `[logging] near "IF": syntax error` while attempting to execute the following code:

```
NSString * saveQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERDB WHERE email=\"%@\")) BEGIN INSERT INTO USERDB (firstName, lastName, username, email, password) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\") END ELSE BEGIN UPDATE USERDB (firstName, lastName, username, email, password) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\") WHERE email = \"%@\" END", email, firstName, lastName, username, email, password, firstName, lastName, username, email, password, email];
[userDB saveData:saveQuery];
```

I am trying to insert into the db, if the user doesn't seem to exist based on their email address (otherwise, I'd like to update their preexisting data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update! Discovered the wonderful world of `INSERT or REPLACE`

```
NSString * saveQuery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO USERDB (firstName, lastName, username, email, password) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", firstName, lastName, username, email, password];
```